# Grub is booting flashes by and reboot

Tags: opensuse, grub

One of my older (yet actually one of my fastest) OpenSuSE TumbleWeed systems apparently didn't take kindly to the latest update.  Everything seemed to apply fine, but on boot after seeing "Grub is booting" (or similar, hard to tell as it flashed by so fast) the system immediately reboots.

How do I troubleshoot this?  Any hope of recovering this system or is it a download media to another machine and reformat situation?

Comment: Is your GRUB configuration file configured to display the GRUB screen for a certain amount of time, such as 10 seconds? For example, my GRUB configuration file has `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`.

Answer (score 1):

I would check your GRUB configuration file. As an example, here is one possible set of configurations in the GRUB configuration file. Probably the most relevant option is GRUB_TIMEOUT=*n*. In the below example GRUB configuration file, GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 tells GRUB to display the GRUB screen for 10 seconds.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Mine looks significantly different, but I don't see anything wrong with it.  Interestingly, I *can* boot off of CD, then select "Boot from hard drive" and start the installed system up.  It just won't boot straight from the hard drive anymore...

Comment: OK. Since your GRUB configuration file differs from mine, would you like to edit your question and share your GRUB configuration file? Once I know what you have in your GRUB configuration file, I will modify my GRUB file to mirror yours, and then see if I can reproduce the issue you are having. This way, we will know if the GRUB configuration file is the source of the issue.